# Missing dll tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow

I have anaconda and python installed and I am trying to use tensorflow through command prompt. Can someone help?

(venv)

`C:\Users\NeravDOSHI>.\venv\Scripts\activate`

(venv)

`C:\Users\NeravDOSHI>python --version`
Python 3.7.6

(venv)

`C:\Users\NeravDOSHI>pip3 --version`
`pip 20.1 from C:\Users\NeravDOSHI\venv\lib\site-packages\pip` (python 3.7)

(venv)

`C:\Users\NeravDOSHI>virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.0.20 from c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py`

(venv)

`C:\Users\NeravDOSHI>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade`

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: tensorflow-1.13.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(venv)

`C:\Users\NeravDOSHI>python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

`File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions from [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). I recommend please [install Tensorflow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#install-tensorflow-2), if you are using lower versions.

You need to download and install/update the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are facing any other issues possible reasons are

- Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
- Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
- There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.

Please refer tested build configurations for windows [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) and [GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).